# TVMet (matrix library) with VS2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, compilation

i'm trying to get tvmet working with VS2010. I have downloaded the TvMet source (http://tvmet.sourceforge.net/), included the include directory in my project settings. I then write

```
#include <tvmet/Matrix.h>

using namespace tvmet;
```

but I get the compile error saying config.h is missing. That's fine. So I copy from the config folder `config-vc71.h`, to the tvmet directory as just `config.h`, but I then get the error

```
"Error  25  error C2244: 'tvmet::CommaInitializer<Obj,LEN>::operator ,' : unable to match function definition to an existing declaration"
```

What this error means and how can I solve it?

Comment: vc71 is Visual Studio 2003 I think - why are you using that one?

Comment: any idea how i can get it to work for vs2010?

Comment: I guess that's a good place to start if there's no more recent config. I expect the problem is subtle C++ syntax changes like that which you'll just have  to work through and fix.

Comment: any hints where i would start? you think i just need to edit the config header file?

Comment: No idea sorry. I'd probably leave the config file alone, assuming it looks sensible, and work through all the errors the compiler gives you solving them - e.g. that declaration one. Or look for another matrix library that has been ported to VS2010, or ask on one of the project mailing lists.

Answer (score 3):

In CommaInitializer.h, inline the implementation of

```
Initializer<value_type, 2> operator,(value_type rhs);
```

from

```
template<class Obj, std::size_t LEN>
typename CommaInitializer<Obj, LEN>::template Initializer<typename Obj::value_type, 2>
CommaInitializer<Obj, LEN>::operator,(typename Obj::value_type rhs)
{
   m_wipeout_on_destruct = false;
   iterator iter1 = m_object.data();
   *iter1         = m_data;
   iterator iter2 = iter1 + 1;
   *iter2         = rhs;
   return Initializer<value_type, 2>(iter2 + 1);
 }
```

to

```
Initializer<value_type, 2> operator,(value_type rhs)
{
 m_wipeout_on_destruct = false;
 iterator iter1 = m_object.data();
 *iter1         = m_data;
 iterator iter2 = iter1 + 1;
 *iter2         = rhs;
 return Initializer<value_type, 2>(iter2 + 1);
}
```

VS doesn't like the ::template keyword in the definition of the function.  If you remove the ::template keyword you will break gcc :(  But if you inline the implementation it should work fine.

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

The following line tries to declare the overloaded comma "," operator function

```
Initializer<value_type, 2> operator,(value_type rhs);
```

But VC++ is not able to match the function definition with its declaration. So I commented out the above line and instead added the following function declaration

```
typename CommaInitializer<Obj, LEN>::template Initializer<typename Obj::value_type, 2>
  CommaInitializer<Obj, LEN>::operator,(typename Obj::value_type rhs);
```